# Nvidia CUDA в Linux Fedora?

Tags: linux, cuda, fedora, nvidia

Как установить CUDA на Linux Fedora для видеокарты Nvidia GeForce 740M. Думал, что после установки драйверов все будет работать, но нет. Пытался найти инормацию в Гугле, но ничего не помогло.

[image: Нема]

На Винде все работало сразу после установки драйверов.

Я начинающий пользователь Федоры и Линукса в целом, поэтому извиняюсь если глупый вопрос.